# Regex pattern which accept only one char or a number group (decimal also)

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to write a regex pattern which allow the user to enter a single character (A or a) or numbers

ex:- A or 94.50

Comment: Uppercase?....... (P.S, do you know that decimals are not `.` all over the world, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
^([A-Z]|([1-9]\d*|0)([.,]\d+)?)$
```

which also avoids matching multiple leading zeros like 00.445

See the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uB8tB3/3)

Comment: Nice catch about the leading `0`s. Up'd

Comment: Thanks, this one fit perfect with my requirement...but if u can tweak it for accepting only (A not case sensitive)  and only two digit after decimal..it will be great

Comment: For case inse insensitive use the flag `/i` and for the two decimals points use `]\d{1,2}` instead of the last `d+`

Comment: where i have to place the '/i'

Comment: How the /i flag is passed depends on the concrete regex implementation you use, e.g. for .NET you can pass it with an enumeration value. As an alternative to the /i flag you could also change the beginning of the regex from ^([A-Z] to ^([a-z][A-Z]

Answer (score 1):

```
^([A-Z]|\d+([.,]\d+)?)$
```

[Here's a Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW6qU3/3)

From start of string `^`
Match `()` a single Uppercase `[A-Z]` or `|`
one number `\d` or more `+`
optionally followed `()?`
by either dot or comma `[.,]` followed by one or more numbers `\d+`
till end of string `$`